# Add an array with itself

Tags: code-golf, array

Your challenge today is to take an array, split it into chunks, and add those chunks.

Here's how this works: Your program or function will be given an array of integers `a` and a chunk size `L`. The array should be split into arrays of size `L`, if the array length is not divisible by `L` then the array should have 0's appended to it so that it is evenly divisible. Once the array is chunked, all chunks are to be added together element-wise. The resulting array is then output.

You can assume `L` is greater than 0, and that `a` is nonempty. You cannot make the assumption that `a`'s contents are positive.

Here's an example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3 => [1,2,3]+[4,5,6]+[7,8,0] =>  [1+4+7,2+5+8,3+6+0] => [12,15,9]
```

Test cases:

```
Array                           Length   Output
[1]                             1        [1]
[1]                             3        [1,0,0]
[0]                             3        [0,0,0]
[1,2]                           3        [1,2,0]
[1,2]                           1        [3]
[-1,1]                          2        [-1,1]
[-7,4,-12,1,5,-3,12,0,14,-2]    4        [12,-1,0,1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]             3        [12,15,18]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Isn't it a dupe?

Comment: @sergiol if you can find a question that this is a duplicate of, I will delete this post myself. However, as far as I can tell it is not  a dupe.

Comment: 7 instead of -7 in test cases

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
e!Xs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1Uxovj//2hdcx0THV1DIx1DHVMdXWMdIMtAxxAoZBTLZQIA)

First bit of MATL code I've written! Takes two inputs, `a` as a row vector (comma-separated) and `l` as a number. Works out to be

```
e          # reshape `a` into `l` rows (auto pads with 0)
 !         # transpose
  Xs       # sum down the columns
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>67</strike> <strike>65</strike> 42 bytes

Uses the fact that the sum of an empty array is 0

```python
lambda x,y:[sum(x[i::y])for i in range(y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/bDoIwFHuWr1h8YklJtoE3kvkjczETQUkUDWAiX49nw9vL0nZtT3of@vOtScdK78aLux6Ojj0x5KZ7XOOnqfN8sLy6taxmdcNa15zKeOB27Muu3xeuKzummTFGWkjQaxFwShgCInARuPhyCfV2qH@F8mlgiQRVKEwgKCtkSKQizwJJCkICkiSKZVSk6NMrnzJqz8i5xAprbKZjFF5Arq21UeQHORxQ@FG/KXk0u7d108f8A7xprrdzVB7yrz5RrQs@vgA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

1 byte thanks to Dennis.

```
;0$¡sS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/aQOXQwuLg////RxvG/jcGAA)

Comment: With a newer version of Jelly, you can do `Ż¡sS` (equivalent to `0;$¡sS`).

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

<sup><s>*Mathematica almost had a builtin for this*</s></sup>

```
Total@Partition[##,#2,1,0]&
```

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

#### Usage

```
Total@Partition[##,#2,1,0]&[{-7, 4, -12, 1, 5, -3, 12, 0, 14, -2}, 4]
```

> `{12, -1, 0, 1}`

#### Explanation

```
Total@Partition[##,#2,1,0]&
      
      Partition[##,#2,1,0]   (* Partition the first input into sublists of length
                                second input, using offset second input, and
                                right-pad zeroes for incomplete partitions *)
Total@                       (* Add all *)
```

Comment: Your link ain't working.

Comment: @Shaggy you have to manually copy and paste the code. Wolfram Sandbox does not support pre-filled inputs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:map(sum,zip(*zip(*[iter(x+n*[0])]*n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9dj4IwEHyWX9H4RLkhaQueH0n9I7W5VIRIIpVATdQ/z@0VvbuXzczszGy2f4Tz1aup0Yfp4rrjybE7/K5zfTreOjzbPs3iMG2oh/T@4TMjLLeZ55xPoR7DV@XGemSaGWOkhQRNi4gLwhAQkYvIxS@XUC@H@q9Qvogsl6AKhRlEZY0SuVTkWSEvQEhAkkSxkooULX@Udxm1l@T8xBobbOdjFF5Bbqy1SdJcB@ZwRMVaz/5e2SWLfmh9iLul3i/RpAT5W56Z1hWbvgE)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

```js
a=>n=>a.map((v,i)=>o[i%n]+=v,o=Array(n).fill(0))&&o
```

Takes input in currying syntax: `f([1,2])(3)`.

### Test Cases

```js
let f=
a=>n=>a.map((v,i)=>o[i%n]+=v,o=Array(n).fill(0))&&o

;[[[1], 1], [[1], 3], [[0], 3], [[1,2], 3], [[1,2], 1], [[-1,1], 2], [[-7,4,-12,1,5,-3,12,0,14,-2], 4], [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3]]
.forEach(([A,N])=>console.log(`${JSON.stringify(A)}, ${N} -> ${f(A)(N)}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: `(a,n,o=[])=>a.map((v,i)=>o[i%n]=~~o[i%n]+v)&&o`

Comment: @Oki Two bytes shorter: `a=>n=>a.map((v,i)=>o[i%=n]=~~o[i]+v,o=[])&&o`, but it doesn't add the required zero-padding.

Comment: `f=` should be part of your character count.

Comment: @nl-x Anonymous functions are allowed by default, so as long as I'm not using the function name in my code, `f=` is not needed. Heres [one post on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/69583) about this.

Comment: @nl-x: No, it shouldn't; a function need only be named if it's recursive (or, maybe, a quine). If it's not then an anonymous function is perfectly valid. See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/58974).

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 58 bytes

```
Total@Partition[PadRight[#,(s=Length@#)+Mod[-s,#2]],{#2}]&
```

**Input**

> [{1},3]

**Output**

> {1,0,0}

Comment: this works for [1],3  You can test it here  https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/    by adding input at the end of the code and pressing shift+enter

Answer (score 4):

### Java 7, 86 bytes

No fancy folds or matrices, just a good ol' fashioned `for` loop :)

```
int[]o(int[]a,int l){int i=0,o[]=new int[l];for(;i<a.length;)o[i%l]+=a[i++];return o;}
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/j3MjBh)

Lined:

```
int[]o(int[]a,int l){
    int i=0,
        o[]=new int[l];
    for(;i<a.length;)
        o[i%l]+=a[i++];
    return o;
}
```

Comment: and with the good ol' fashioned Java 7 (instead of 8). ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
S↑ȯ¡¬Fż+C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/hR28QT6w8tPLTG7egebef///@b/I/WNdcx0dE1NNIx1DHV0TXWAbIMdAyBQkaxAA)

#### Explanation

```
        C    Cut into lists of length n
     Fż+     Sum them element-wise
  ȯ¡¬        Append infinitely many 0s
S↑           Take the first n elements
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 36 bytes

```perl6
{[Z+] flat(@^a,0 xx$^b*2).rotor($b)}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##jZFPb4JAEMXv@ynmoAV0WFkQtRINPfTmoYemhxJNUNeWBIGwa0Nj/Ox0EWMhTY172Oyf38ubeZPxPB6VB8Hha0Q3HnnJ030kOI0S3TWo/OTJ9MiLSJ7I/hseNumWw6w8Bu/9JeziUOr@KkQLiqKzWvdsg@apTHO9szZOpeJ9yYWEGcRRwoVu0H2YTaFHn9@eFh6pPF/Vv0eyOEygf4Y9skvzi86cg@6H2InR50XGN5JvDTgSgEiYW86z@BuqemrGoItISIQrWt8VLbI8SuQONB26jiVQ7QIMAJjNoctcoVUQgB/STGVBxWEtpD7QQBugpuH0w6j/VRk1dzX4B/fIqQwY2ujgEF0c4RgnS4T2cq4PAbORufi4JAH7g7UXa4juwJseaKGlJNb9EusiUZ3cFLVc7LskjT4chZsMb7Zi/@JnVCnGKlqzCk4FbDqoThYy9XTxHbbSNavuWV1Xcygqc7w9FDZZ/gA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with 2 placeholder parameters ｢@a｣, ｢$b｣
  [Z+]
    flat(
      @^a,         # declare and use the first parameter
      0 xx $^b * 2 # 0 list repeated 2 * the second parameter
    )
    .rotor($b)     # split into chunks that are the size of the second param
}
```

```perl6
[1,2], 3

( [1,2], (0,0,0,0,0,0) ) # @^a,0 xx$^b*2
(1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)        # flat(…)
( (1,2,0), (0,0,0) )     # .rotor($b) # (drops partial lists)
(1,2,0)                  # [Z+]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 8 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
+˝↑˙⊸⋈⊸⥊
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgICvLneKGkcuZ4oq44ouI4oq44qWKIAojRiDihpAgeyvLneKGkeKAv/CdlanipYrwnZWofQoK4oCiU2hvdyAxIEYg4p+oMeKfqQrigKJTaG93IDMgRiDin6gx4p+pCuKAolNob3cgMyBGIOKfqDDin6kK4oCiU2hvdyAzIEYg4p+oMSwy4p+pCuKAolNob3cgMSBGIOKfqDEsMuKfqQrigKJTaG93IDIgRiDin6gtMSwx4p+pCuKAolNob3cgNCBGIOKfqC03LDQsLTEyLDEsNSwtMywxMiwwLDE0LC0y4p+pCuKAolNob3cgMyBGIOKfqDEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw54p+p)

`{+˝↑‿⥊}` is 1 longer. BQN's reshape is very good.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>62</s> 57 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to user2390246*

```r
function(a,l)rowSums(matrix(c(a,rep(0,l-sum(a|1)%%l)),l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEbhvadwOSN/wGkrYmlP4QEkFCOFToJJgy68e0y7e3y8WNxxMMVlP61z8GSxcAyfe9ZEpKPaNc7fXflE6fl@2CX4FykPY8pK9ifMXBxJf0PLB0cTmSs6GGkguMC0qHWGVGoY3bZIPcsf)

Updated since it no longer has to handle the empty case.

pads `a` with zeros, constructs a matrix of `l` rows, and computes and returns the row sums.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpNCoMwEIbhfU/hRpiBb8Dxh1LpLXqCIAaEREs06KJ3T8fdy8uTiq/eUnxep2PZVnIInLbzk@NO0R1puWiymeYvNQiy50jup1zXgdkoF086vtDxwxuUJ3qItlAMkA5WDdRWy@hvoibLHw)

Comment: @user2390246 of course! I had that in an older version when we had to handle the empty case but this one was my "primary" and I didn't think to try that again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
m+F%Q>vz
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2BF%25Q%3Evz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A%5B%5D%0A%0A1%0A%5B1%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B0%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%0A1%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%0A2%0A%5B-1%2C1%5D%0A%0A4%0A%5B-7%2C4%2C-12%2C1%2C5%2C-3%2C12%2C0%2C14%2C-2%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
sMCc.[EZQQ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sMCc.%5BEZQQ&input=3%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A%5B%5D%0A%0A1%0A%5B1%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B0%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%0A1%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%0A2%0A%5B-1%2C1%5D%0A%0A4%0A%5B-7%2C4%2C-12%2C1%2C5%2C-3%2C12%2C0%2C14%2C-2%5D%0A%0A3%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

## Explanation

#### Explanation #1

```
m+F%Q>vz   Full program. Q means input.

m          Map over the implicit range [0, input_1), with a variable d.
     >vz  All the elements of input_2 after d; input_2[d:] in Python.
   %Q     Every Qth element of ^.
 +F       Sum. Implicitly output the result.
```

#### Explanation #2

```
sMCc.[EZQQ   Full program.

    .[E      Pad the second input to the right, with repeated copies of...
       Z     ... Zero (0), up to the nearest multiple of...
        Q    ... The first input.
   c     Q   Chop into chunks of length equal to the first input.
  C          Matrix transpose. Get all the columns of the nested list.
sM           Sum each.
             Output (implicitly).
```

Comment: How about something like this: `sM.TcEQ`

Comment: @Jakube That is incorrect, as you have to pad with zeros first. That was Leaky's initial attempt, but would fail for `[1], 3`, which would give `[1]` instead of `[1, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>59</s> 49 bytes

```hs
a%l=[sum$map((0:a)!!)[i,l+i..length a]|i<-[1..l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHBTsMwDIbveQpPWqVNOFOctGwgduCOxANUOURiYhFpqbr2gIBnL2YD2nFIN2k5Wcn3x7/9b93uZRNC17kkrPNdW0wLV81m6tbNJ5N57jFc@cUibMrnZgvOfvg7mRNfWNsVzpewhqdXAVXtywamkJOFyEmAzmDNgFVnsITaXood@pWEEcsJ6CG7xBQlaSTMUBrkSiHx1b5dAumxBzSMZ3iNS1zhjf3vV7xLcV/X7i2yg4dDRACPbVO1jRhZL9BvweAobHqY51AsUKcK1I8gvumjDvoUQe/fMBzPBvQfvAfFSD6Q9m40Y99vB0eRoIYj8L8Z0soK@dl9AQ)

Comment: I don't know if I'm allowed to submit a solution in a language that has already been done, so I'll post my solution here: (79 bytes)
```l%a|l>length a=t|1>0=zipWith(+)t$l%drop l a where t=take l$a++repeat 0```

Comment: @Itay123 Posting your own Haskell solution is perfectly fine! As per our Help center (and meta consensus), an answer only needs to be a valid solution of the challenge and make some effort towards the winning criteria. It does not have to be the shortest solution, and for me it's always interesting to see different approaches. So please go ahead and post your answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Takes `l` as left argument and `a` a right argument.

```apl
{+⌿s⍴⍵↑⍨×/s←⍺,⍨⌈⍺÷⍨≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zEl5VHbhGrtRz37ix/1bnnUu/VR28RHvSsOT9cvBko86t2lA@Q96ukAsg5vBzE7FwEV1f7//6hvqlewv5@CoQLQDAUoTz3aMFadCyZlTLSUAR5dOkZIkob4JI1QJXUNdZCtNEGTNdcx0dE1NNIx1DHV0TXWAbIMdAyBQkZ43aJjDNRmqmOmY65joWMZqw4A)

`{`…`}` anonymous function where `⍺` is the left argument (`l`) and `⍵` the right argument (`a`).

`≢⍵` tally (length) of `a`

`⍺÷⍨` divide by `l`

`⌈` ceiling (round up)

`⍺,⍨` append `l`

`s←` store in `s` (for **s**hape)

`×/` product of that (i.e. how many integers are needed)

`⍵↑⍨` take that many integers from `a` (padding with zeros)

`s⍴` **r**eshape to shape `s` (rows, columns)

`+⌿` columnar sums

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 40 bytes

```perl6
{[Z+] (|@^a,|(0 xx*)).rotor($^l)[0..@a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3NDoIwEITvPEUTObQ6kG7LnyEmPIcEEg56wmDQA0Z89rqIgRizl535Znavp75N3OUh/LM4CPcsj7tKyLGoG4xSi2HYKhX23b3rpV@3qtRhWDTVy@Wed2umlpQaCsKqXGwE7zxqQQSzMhb/jGZmsYKAQEzMTD5qZSkiBGRAiBFY8KZBbPGt6PvGcGByf17BcjFGghQZ9gp2CVMMypR7Aw)

If you like the number 42, you can swap the `*` for an `∞`. That will make it 42 bytes :—).

**Explanation**:

```perl6
{[Z+] (|@^a,|(0 xx*)).rotor($^l)[0..@a]} The whole function
{                                      } Anonymous block
      (    ,        )                    List with 2 elements
        @^a                              The first argument (it is a list)
             (0 xx*)                     Infinite list of zeroes
       |    |                            Flatten both of the lists into the larger list.
                    .rotor($^l)          Split the list into a list of lists, each (the second argument) long.
                               [0..@a]   Only the first (1 + length of the first argument) of them.
 [Z+]                                    Add the corresponding elements up.
```

The magic behind the last "add up" is that the operator is a "reduce with zip with +". By the way, this would break down if we used it only on a list with 1 list inside, but that never happens if the original list was non-empty (due to the second-to-last row). Also note that we end up taking not only `@a`, but `@a * $l` items. Fortunately we added only zeroes which won't affect the final result.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
]{.+/@(]\~-)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/2Or9bT1HTRiY@p0Nf9rcinpKain2VqpK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrGCpoRFvHWqdpKhiiCxhDBAzQBQwVjPAJQc2JN0QyyggqZq5gApQwAsqYKsQbKwBZBgqGQCGEbhOEgcZAxaYKZgrmChYKlggb/wMA)

### Explanation

```
]{.+/@(]\~-)  Input: array A (LHS), chunk size L (RHS)
          -   Negate L
       ]\~    Take each non-overlapping sublist of size L in A
   +/@        Reduce the columns by addition
]             Get L
 {.           Take that many, filling with 0's
```

Comment: Any reason we can't do away with the boxes? What about: `[:+/-@[[\]`?

Comment: @Jonah If the chunk size is larger than the length of the input array, it won't be zero-padded.

Comment: Nice edit -- much cleaner now.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ô0ζO²Å0+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8BaDc9v8D2063Gqg/f9/tKGOglEslzEA)

```
ô0ζO²Å0+   Full program
ô          Push <1st input> split into a list of <2nd input> pieces
 0ζ        Zip sublists with 0 as a filler
   O       Sum each sublist
           --- from here, the program handles outputs shorter 
               than the required length
    ²Å0    Push a list of zeros of length <2nd input>
       +   Sum the result with that list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Å0+¹ô0ζO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cKuB9qGdh7cYnNvm//@/MVe0oY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjmUsAA)

```
Å0       # Push an arrary of all 0s with length l
  +      # Add that to the array
   ¹ô    # Split into chunks of length l
     0ζ  # Zip, padding with 0s
       O # Sum each chunk
```

Comment: Almost identical to my own solution: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143186/73296

Comment: @scottinet I must have missed that. They are different enough that I'll leave mine and upvote yours :)

Comment: I don't really mind, just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: @scottinet It is interesting that you can rearrange the operations and come out with the same byte count and almost identical bytes used (`¹` vs `²`)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ẇR∆ZR∩Ṡ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuodS4oiGWlLiiKnhuaAiLCIiLCI0XG5bLTcsNCwtMTIsMSw1LC0zLDEyLDAsMTQsLTJdIl0=)

Comment: afaict the zfilling is unecessary as the missing zeroes are simply ignored

Comment: @emanresuA that would fail on case `[1,2], 3 => [1,2,0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
l⁵%⁵κ{0+}nI⌡∑¹
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=bCV1MjA3NSUyNSV1MjA3NSV1MDNCQSU3QjArJTdEbkkldTIzMjEldTIyMTElQjlGJTBBLiUyQyV1MjE5MkY_,inputs=NCUwQSU1Qi03JTJDNCUyQy0xMiUyQzElMkM1JTJDLTMlMkMxMiUyQzAlMkMxNCUyQy0yJTVE) or [Try all the test-cases.](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=bCV1MjA3NSUyNSV1MjA3NSV1MDNCQSU3QjArJTdEbkkldTIzMjEldTIyMTElQjlGJTBBaW5wdXRzLnZhbHVlJXUyMDFEJXUyMTkyJUI2JXUwMzk4JTdCJXUwM0I4X3IlM0IldTIxOTJGQCV1MjIxMVA_,inputs=JTVCMSU1RCUyMDElMEElNUIxJTVEJTIwMyUwQSU1QjAlNUQlMjAzJTBBJTVCMSUyQzIlNUQlMjAzJTBBJTVCMSUyQzIlNUQlMjAxJTBBJTVCLTElMkMxJTVEJTIwMiUwQSU1Qi03JTJDNCUyQy0xMiUyQzElMkM1JTJDLTMlMkMxMiUyQzAlMkMxNCUyQy0yJTVEJTIwNCUwQSU1QjElMkMyJTJDMyUyQzQlMkM1JTJDNiUyQzclMkM4JTJDOSU1RCUyMDM_) this is written as an unnamed function and expects `chunk length; array` on the stack.

Explanation:

```
padding zeroes
l          get the array's length
 ⁵%        modulo the chunk length
   ⁵κ      chunk length - result of above
     {  }  that many times
      0+     append a 0 to the array

adding the array together
n      split into the chunks
 I     rotate clockwise
  ⌡    for each
   ∑     sum
    ¹  wrap the results in an array
```

Comment: What's the `F` for in the Try it Here code you linked?

Comment: @Pavel the functions name. The same as in JS `f=a=>a+2` the `f=` part isn't counted - in SOGL `F\n` isn't counted.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
gs÷*+Å0¹+ôøO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/vfjwdi3tw60Gh3ZqH95yeIf////RuuY6Jjq6hkY6hjqmOrrGOkCWgY4hUMgolssEAA)

#### Explanation

```
gs÷*+Å0¹+ôøO
g            # Get the length of the first input (the array)
 s           # Push the second input on top of the result
  ÷          # integer divide the two values
   *         # Multiply with the second input (the length)...
    +        # and add the second input to the result
     Å0      # Create a list of zeros with that length
       ¹+    # Add it to the first input
         ô   # And finally split it into chunks of the input length...
          ø  # ...transpose it...
           O # and sum each resulting subarray
             # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
Plus@@#~ArrayReshape~{⌈Tr[1^#]/#2⌉,#2}&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
Fż+So:`R0C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@3oHu3gfKuEIAPn////G/@PNtQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdex0LGMBQA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
             -- implicit inputs n & xs                   | 3  [1,2,3,4]
   S      C  -- cut xs into sublists of length n & ...   | [[1,2,3], [4]]
    (:`R0)   -- ... prepend [0,...,0] (length n)         | [[0,0,0], [1,2,3], [4]]
F            -- accumulate the sublists with             |
 ż+          -- element-wise addition                    | [0+1+4, 0+2, 0+3]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 42 bytes

```clj
#(apply map +(partition %2 %2(repeat 0)%))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsMgFET3OcVACfxPEaImTe8SspBWwWLNR8yipzduC7N4PB7zSsfnLL7R2weEdiMnkn74OsGdxJUaazwyRtNHxYt3FROPzI2HgaTEXFMGBWxqxQylDTQWKItOE3RXZsfM/B9rGNjeL3hgxXOH7Y8X)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 31 bytes

```
[_nwise($n)]|transpose|map(add)
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mc --argjson n 3 '[_nwise($n)]|transpose|map(add)' <<< "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"
[12,15,9]
```

Takes advantage of builtins: [_nwise](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L100), [transpose](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L190), [add](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L11) and [map](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

Man, I fought with the wrong Japt method for far too long trying to get it to work for the `[1], 3` test case in a reasonable amount of bytes!

```
VÆëVX x
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VsbrVlggeA==&input=Wy03LDQsLTEyLDEsNSwtMywxMiwwLDE0LC0yXQo0Ci1R)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U` and integer `V`.

```
VÆ
```

Generate an array of integers from `0` to `V-1` and pass each through a function with `X` being the current element.

```
ëVX
```

Grab every `V`th element of `U`, beginning at index `X`.

```
x
```

Reduce that array by addition.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 24 bytes

```
[:@z#<[0 z rpad]map sum]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BDoIwEETv/YpJagIkSmiLokgM/4EEG4GLITYFLvx83aImHjzN29nJ7I6Tvj@61rkqLxdeVAkWWKPbetAG4zzUrsx7FjIgFJBQSLHHARmOEdTqfjT5zpC/JDw1AhSTK2bU0AgJQT2NAlECQRZl0z9XcPJtEZO8YKzKEccxetjOWFyxWdV/GpwRgN/I41ui3eU9Puep9nv3Ag)

### Explanation

```
[:@z#<[0 z rpad]map sum]
[                      ]   anonymous function
 :@z                       stores TOS as `z` (the length)
    #<                     cut STOS in TOS slices
      [        ]map        for each slice
       0 z rpad               pad the slice with `z` zeroes
                    sum]   summate all inner slices
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 64 bytes

```java
n->a->{int k=0,r[]=new int[n];for(int i:a)r[k++%n]+=i;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVE9b4MwEN3zK26pBMJYQNJPClKXSh2aJSNicAlEJuRAxqSKIn47PQhplmwNveXOfnfvvbNzsRd2WaWYr7dd1XwVMoGkEHUNn0IiHGczoKi10ARkEkUBOY3wRsuCZw0mWpbIP1C/j/XrFfgXk6ijmMGQwhCWEHRoh8IOj3QF28BhKooDTL@HFoz9rFRGD8kXYapoa1l3GFuB9FWqG4Wg/Lbr/fknm6P/0e2@lGvY0RbGSiuJmygGoTa1SUvBGKtDrdMdLxvNK2rRBRoX@29KiUPNdXkaN5ZcVFVxMFxzLM4@Yzi6rWma/t945//I60zll4F3A2p3OmrvCrVN3Ld46cU17kcGCwa265EGg3sq51TRyaHUI96Ef8FgPsiT7AMDsvLE4Pmi187a7gc)

Answer (score 2):

## C, (GCC) <strike>101</strike> 86 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEXX9VcMhgQ9RtDWaWtQ/CXGC@HGyYBkFysQiNG3O2Ol7eYgHc0d3d6c@35dB0HjVTlkgs@MG1WQCw0iMllR4@3tQv4kaL9nF1pvyJhON8ppbaMxNg3CoceIQdqU1i0VHI1CwlIAQF4PDVT27@baumOxvOE7VnjAD/zEL6zT/4AK/CzySQbn/dSLSPfTlBtLUOBlnt0@5upQI4RfM83PIDWvFuhYMbTemrz8zOwHUe6@EUoMLXXPSCrS@gA)

```
f(int*a,int l,int s,int*m){if(s){int i=l;while(i&&s){m[l-i--]+=*a++;s--;}f(a,l,s,m);}}
```

### Usage

```
int main() {
   int l = 3;
   int a[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   int *m = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * l);
   f(a, l, 8, m);
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("%d, ",m[i]);
   }
}
```

Note that you have to pass in the length of the array (s) and a new dynamic array on the heap (m).

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY7bCsIwEESf7VcsBSWXDaj1Uoj9EulDqEYWklYan2z77TWtt5dl58wMTKVuVTWOpC0z6DCg51Q/hEHhdUeWBW6bllHhNK1Woe//Mc2DUujPTpFSpSyEkVIPY2yDN1QzDl0CAJN2UECmv8qc8zKCboNbzHCHezzgEfPhFxA@2mz@uDfONRUL9Lw2dmIcBDg@Z6ct4BByBP8hTfsuUrHWQKcsHimnJYt7G7ll6fKCkMbZVL4rQzKMLw).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->a,n{b=[w=0]*n;a.map{|r|b[w%n]+=r;w+=1};b}
```

I wanted to outgolf at least python, but I couldn't, so here is the best I could do.

#### How it works:

- create an array of size n filled with zeroes
- iterate on the input array, and calculate sums, repeat wrapping around the output array

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyxCsIwGIR3n6KLS3uR/ElrlRBfJGRIhm6GEpAgbZ89TcWq4Pbdcd/Fh3/mQWd2cwiT1yZpbuug3OnuxmmOszfpGGyjo0qNpkX5JY/VYAxZVGQPH5Zv5j9MEH9pdxhh08Qee7RgJEDowCQKcVCpNqf9PkCWXYczelxwfb3nFQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```julia
V\n=sum(reshape([V;zeros(n-endof(V)%n,1)],n,:),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/LCbPtrg0V6MotTgjsSBVIzrMuiq1KL9YI083NS8lP00jTFM1T8dQM1YnT8dKU8dI83@0qY6RjrGOuY6hjpFBbIxJjV1BUWZeSU6ewn8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 62 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$l)1..$l|%{$y=--$_;($o=0)..$l|%{$o+=$a[$y+$_*$l]};$o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVH01BPTyWnRrVapdJWV1cl3lpDJd/WQBMmmK9tq5IYrVKprRKvpZITW2utkl/7//9/Bw1DHSPN/8YA)

We take input `$a`rray and `$l`ength. Then loop from `1` to `$l`. Each iteration we set helper `$y` to be one less than the current number (this is because PowerShell 0-indexes but the `$l`ength is in 1-indexing). Then we set our `$o`utput to `0` and loop again up to `$l`. Each inner iteration we're simply accumulating into `$o` the appropriately-indexed `$a`rray element. This leverages the fact that indexing past the end of the array returns `$null` and `0 + $null = 0`.

Once the inner loop is done, we output `$o` and move on to the next chunk. The various outputs are left on the pipeline and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens on program completion.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 + 1 (-a) = 45 bytes

```perl
@r=(0)x($l=<>);map$r[$i++%$l]+=$_,@F;say"@r"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@hyFbDQLNCQyXH1sZO0zo3sUClKFolU1tbVSUnVttWJV7Hwc26OLFSyaFI6f9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMFcwULLuN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usmAgA)

*Edit: fixed the case where the length requested was smaller than the input array*

Answer (score 1):

## **[Scala 2.12.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/)**, 80 bytes

```
(a:Array[Int],b:Int)=>(0 to b-1).map(i=>a.indices.filter(_%b==i).collect(a).sum)
```

It is slightly shorter than the Java solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
f=(a,l)=>(r=Array(l).fill(0),a.forEach((c,i)=>r[i%l]+=c),r)
```

### usage

```
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3);
// returns [12, 15, 9]
```

### edit 1

According to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) in the comments, the `f=` part is not needed if the function is not recursive. So:

```
(a,l)=>(r=Array(l).fill(0),a.forEach((c,i)=>r[i%l]+=c),r)
```

with usage off course of:

```
((a,l)=>(r=Array(l).fill(0),a.forEach((c,i)=>r[i%l]+=c),r))([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3)
// returns [12, 15, 9]
```

### edit 2

Golfing down 1 more character, as the extra parenthesis are no longer needed then.

```
(a,l,r=Array(l).fill(0))=>a.forEach((c,i)=>r[i%l]+=c)||r
```

with usage off course of:

```
((a,l,r=Array(l).fill(0))=>a.forEach((c,i)=>r[i%l]+=c)||r)([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3)
// returns [12, 15, 9]
```

Comment: You were [beaten to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143122/58974).

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think that solution is correct as per the rules. Also he is leaving out the `f=` part that should count for more characters.

Comment: How so? It's identical to yours, just more golfed. Functions only need to be assigned to a variable if they're recursive.

Comment: The assignment is a program or a function that returns the resulting array. This function returns another function that needs to be executed again. Also the `f=` part is needed to call the function. If it is not needed, I can also golf down 2 characters.

Comment: Currying, like anonymous functions, is also perfectly valid. See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8427/58974).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 33 bytes

```
a->l->Vecrev(Polrev(a)%(x^l-1),l)
```

Converts `a` to a polynomial, mod `x^l-1`, and then converts it back to a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y5H1y4sNbkotUwjID8HRCVqqmpUxOXoGmrq5Gj@LyjKzCvRSNOINtQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdexiNXUMNbU5IJLG6AL6JoDFesaGukYArXoGusAWQY6hkAhI6BKE03N/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 90 bytes

```
(lambda(a l)(dotimes(i(-(length a)l)(subseq a 0 l))(incf(elt a(mod i l))(elt a (+ l i)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctLDsIwEAPQq3iHRwgJWn7XmTYBRpq0haTnD2m985M9uuWlcvnZNIKVrmkISoULw1wsxUzjiR6nd/lApXlehxy/UJzbStieL0YvUKY5wHbcO3iEw2RLPfCCDj2uuOGOB56CvvEf)

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX shell, 45 bytes

This requires the utilities `jot` and `rs` to be installed, as well as the more common `sed` and `bc`.  The chunk size is passed as the first argument, and the array as space-separated values on standard input

```sh
(jot -b0 $1;cat)|rs -tjg1 -C+ $1|sed s/.//|bc
```

The `jot` command generates a row full of zeros (in case the chunk size is smaller than the input); `cat` appends the input, then `rs` transforms that into the specified number of rows.  Each line now begins with `+`, and `bc` won't accept that, so remove it with `sed` before performing the summation of each line.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 75 bytes

```
a=>n=>(a++Seq.fill(n-a.size/n)(0)).grouped(n).toSeq.transpose.map(_.sum)
```

To use this, you have to add a type:

```
val f:(Seq[Int]=>Int=>Seq[Int])=
    a=>n=>(a++Seq.fill(n-a.size/n)(0)).grouped(n).toSeq.transpose.map(_.sum)

f(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 25 bytes

```
D,f,@@*,d0b]*$@$+TbUpBcBs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xCsIwEIbn9Cn@oVNt4S5pbUUIobi76CQZrKFzwPcnXiPFDGbKfd/d/fcMIcaULu3aOte0gRbf1K4@3JZ7nF/zO9WrfbBX8qxidVZSVNeqpCZTEGg3VBoqDUP7ckj/UTnF7Lhj8JfrjedyVyN6dKzBGNAZyI/AgmSRVX1O0NKw0SIFRsYGHDFiwsn/rpFFA3iS1vQB)

### How it works

First, we define our function \$f(a, x)\$. It takes two arguments (`@@`) and returns the entire stack (`*`), rather than the top element. Here, \$a\$ denotes the array of elements, such as \$a := [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]\$, and \$x\$ represents slice length, \$x := 4\$ for example. The stack is \$[a, x]\$ at the start of execution. We then duplicate \$x\$, and repeat \$[0]\$ \$x\$ times. We call this array \$z\$, rearrange the stack so it looks like \$[x, a, z]\$ and concatenate \$a\$ with \$z\$. This appends \$x\$ zeroes to the end of \$a\$.

Next, we take slices of length \$x\$ from \$a ^ \frown z\$. For the example inputs above, this would yield \$[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 0, 0], [0, 0]]\$. For every possible inputs, this yields an array where the final element always contains only superfluous zeroes, so we splat the elements of the array to the stack and remove the last element. Finally, we zip the arrays together and take the sum of each.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras math.unicode`, 47 bytes

```factor
[ [ 0 pad-groups ] keep group flip [ Σ ] map ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
function(a,l,m=matrix(a,l))rowSums(m*(seq(m)<=seq(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoMwEEX3nqLLmfIDnWgpip7CE4RgQOgojQa9fZqs3n@fF3N4jCaHtPlz3Tdy@EIndWdc7yrMcb/mpAfpk47lR8rjVOmYOQeSoUfLTSBP5oMORiwEb5gWZb0g5bKMriZSyvwH)

Somewhat based on [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143110/95126), but uses a different trick to counteract [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s recycling the first elements of `a` to fill the last chunk.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 21 bytes

```
J0bcj.+2MVj_+jcotp)++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLCsIwEEX3fsXFnYRIJmltpdAPENzqSoSWbkrB@ugq5Nvj1GptXdQODIRwMrlzsuZWFfdrU3i7lOkySeSpLvxOZXm5Fnp/KM@izC@PeiWEd8fKW4KGQYAQG0SIHcZluGUKWNKgEFu3sPTLjIv6F//Z73QoKObVTF69eU7v5s3Xc/g@u2FWEqbi6w/74hiP2KJsNbFLacAnBeKr7sdgIFK261IXZyif9U7Jp9g9AQ)

```
J    # Dup L
0bc  # Infinite list of zeros
j.+  # Select L 0s
2MV  # Put list at top of stack
j_+  # Append zeros
jco  # Split into chunks of length L
tp   # Transpose
)++  # Map sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C(GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 44 bytes

```c
m(a,L,l,o)int*a,*o;{for(;l--;)o[l%L]+=a[l];}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bZDRaoMwFIav26cIHYXEHkXTdl1JHXi1m16tsBsnojbOQDSj7QZb8dndiaOtjF3@33/ynUMK960oujvVFPpjLzfH014Zr3ocD4lWeY/2slSNJO8H1Zw@ZUEjIDn7jSWdxBMmSnOgmIgKfaE2NGdCzWbsMjFVMIEoVgkTF5S8NvjsqpbZ8YtuIQfP8xi52khIrI/7va5CA/pJTW0bJyxNX6I0en7apSnYxxUTtyMr2DLR1TTDSoNhiJ0MHCPOVi@06wpmYj3dJrMwi3Ui2s7urDPVUHYej2xwqrDOtDYFPapvaUq7lzncx8tH/ckBBHAO2mue/5f9YebYA28Hhr@EW@Ki@YYWEPjIVrAAN@DoXIKLag4@BIj4cMG618EcZ5dwDyt4gHXflwcpKX7RuO1@AA) It doesn't get more stupid than this :) In the tio version, i added a few macros, but they only help me do the tests in main more easily, and aren't used in the actual function. It modifies a given array instead of directly outputting one, because that's a real pain to do in c. It expects a zeroed array in o.

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, <s>106</s> 71 bytes

```
l=[1...s]
f(a,s)=[∑_{q=1}^{ceil(a.length/s)}join(a,l0)[qs-s+t]fort=l]
```

*-35 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1xqq8dbiqb)

Comment: [94 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eqktmo23lf) with various smaller golfs.

Comment: Actually, [86 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/baxzlslcpb)

Comment: Seems like you don't need to subtract `mod(k,s)`: [75 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ogbqeduqux)

Comment: Oh wait once you take out that, you don't even need `k` anymore: [71 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/byvct9yj6v)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẇ0Ƭʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQSU4NzAlQzYlQUMlQ0ElODImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIxJTJDMiUyQzMlMkM0JTJDNSUyQzYlMkM3JTJDOCU1RCUwQTMmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ẇ0Ƭʂ  # Implicit input - A (array), N (integer)
ẇ     # Split (A) into chunks of length (N)
 0Ƭ   # Transpose the list with filler 0
   ʂ  # Sum each inner list
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/+⬚0↯~
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgLyvirJow4oavfgoKZiAxIFsxXQpmIDMgWzFdCmYgMyBbMF0KZiAzIFsxIDJdCmYgMSBbMSAyXQpmIDIgW8KvMSAxXQpmIDQgW8KvNyA0IMKvMTIgMSA1IMKvMyAxMiAwIDE0IMKvMl0KZiAzIFsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOV0K)

```
/+⬚0↯~
    ↯~  # reshape into matrix with number of columns indicated by input
  ⬚0    # filling excess elements with zeros
/+      # sum columns
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
V\n=1:n.|>i->sum(V[i:n:end])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY89bsMwDIV3n4IIMsgAbUhynB8DNnqBrl5SDQKiAipU1pCcTL27y9ZtPTU1J4L8Ht/jyzV4u5@m/ola1VD53vmiS9dX0Z99Q42ji8mn57cIHjxBdPYSPLkk8gy4eiR00IK72VCKRzfacrAxuVKkIfhR@DyfwSF6GgOJzbaHLUHbwQbZcl4@2JRcHIEH0PKxjF2nszJwr9RPw2D2H1wtMEqULJBrBfJboFCblQ56jWDJXzFcKLz3gv6Fv0DmD7jDQmlUWGNRIXcSFY9mz92SRjP2uZsTYcW6Gvd4wCOezF8v8N0a1dF8AA)

also works in Julia 1.0+